# Liberty Batch function not using database persistence for job repository

Tags: websphere-liberty, open-liberty, jsr352

I'm trying to use database [persistence](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/core?topic=liberty-java-batch-persistence-configuration) with the Open Liberty batch features.  However, I'm seeing nothing inserted into my DB tables and I see this message in **messages.log**:

> ... I CWWKY0005I: The batch In-Memory persistence service is activated.

#### server.xml

In my server configuration, I have:

```xml
    <!-- Batch features -->
    <featureManager>
        <feature>cdi-3.0</feature>
        <feature>batch-2.0</feature>
        <feature>batchManagement-1.0</feature>
        ...
    <featureManager>

    <!-- Configure JDBC library -->
    <library id="jdbcLib">
        <fileset dir="/config/lib/global" includes="*.jar"/>
    </library>

    <!-- Configure dataSource -->
    <dataSource id="batchDB" jdbcDriverRef="jdbcLib">
      <properties.db2.jcc>
       ... a bunch of properties ...
      </properties.db2.jcc> 
    </dataSource>

    <!-- Reference datasource with batch DB store -->

    <batchPersistence jobStoreRef="BatchDatabaseStore"/>

    <databaseStore id="BatchDatabaseStore"
                   dataSourceRef="batchDB" schema="JBATCH" tablePrefix=""
                   createTables="false"/>
```

What am I doing wrong?

#### NOTE

Sometimes when batch database persistence is working the `CWWKY0005I` message is followed by the message

> CWWKY0008I: The batch feature is using persistence type JPA.

as the batch persistence component dynamically activates later on, but this is NOT happening in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your server.xml config, you missed a layer of wrappering (abstraction) here by referencing the **`<library>`** directly with `jdbcDriverRef="jdbcLib"` when you should have referenced a **`<jdbcDriver>`**.

So you could have used in your server.xml either:

```xml
    <library id="jdbcLib">
       ...

    <dataSource id="batchDB">
      <jdbcDriver libraryRef="jdbcLib"/>
       ... 
    </dataSource>
```

or, alternately

```xml
    <library id="jdbcLib">
       ...
    <jdbcDriver id="myJDBCDriver" libraryRef="jdbcLib"/>

    <dataSource id="batchDB" jdbcDriverRef="myJDBCDriver">
       ...
```

to have your dataSource referencing a jdbcDriver which, in turn, references a library.